# Oracle 11g login error- says account locked

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I recentely installed oracle 11g in my windows xp(virtual box guest) i tried to login to sqlplus using scott/tiger credentials. but it throws the below error.

ORA-28000:THE ACOUNT IS LOCKED.

could someone please advise me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to log on using a DBA account and unlock the SCOTT account using

```
  ALTER USER scott ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

**UPDATE**

To log on as the SYS user, use this (this will only work locally):

```
  sqlplus /nolog
  sqlplus> conn / as sysdba
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply..could you please let me know how to login  using a DBA account ?Sorry..I am very new to this..

Comment: thanks Frank. i was able o log in. i opened cmd window and gave the command 'sqlplus sys as sysdba' and inside it i gave your alter user query..and then i logged into sqlplus. It asked me for a change of password. now it is working fine